# Using ASP.Net 4.0 for new Dev projects

Tags: .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I am currently in the early stages of developing a couple web applications, I have not written any code yet as I am still just gathering requirements and scoping things out. I want to target ASP.Net 4.0 winforms as the platform for these apps but I want to make sure there are no glaring issues with this new version before I commit.

I understand that if I was porting an existing app from 2.0, 3.5 to 4.0 there may be issues but I am starting from scratch on these projects and plan to write these apps to support the new features of 4.0.

Should I wait for the first service pack to come out? Just seems like more work to start with 3.5 now only to go back through and tweak things for 4.0 in just a few months or even before I finish the app.

Our servers are Win 2K3 with IIS6 and MS SQL 2000, Should I expect any problems with VS 2010 and MS SQL 2000 in regards to Linq to SQL and EF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it. I do the same at the moment. SQL 2000, though - is out of support. Even the bank I am sitting in at the moment is now replacing it with 2005 / 2008. I would seriously consider upgrades.

Web application? Using SPLA (only legal licensing for service providers - purchased licenses are not legal here) you get 2008R2 and SQL 2008 R2 anyway.